# Django problem "super() argument 1 must be type, not WSGIRequest" in Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, super

While to use class inheritance, Python 3 fails with `super() argument 1 must be type, not WSGIRequest`.

I'm on Django 2.1.4 and Python 3.7.0. I am trying to see if a user already submitted an file to be analyzed, if not, he is directed to the submission page. I've tried to do not use static methods, check if it's really Python 3 (because this problem is common on Python 2), on the super class I tried to inherit from "object" while also inheriting from "View" provided by Django (because this solves in Python 2 [super() argument 1 must be type, not None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474023/super-argument-1-must-be-type-not-none)).

This is the super class, it inherits from the class provided by Django "View".

```
class DatasetRequired(View):

    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        <redirects the user>
```

This is the base class

```
class Estatisticas(DatasetRequired):

    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        super(request)
        <do various other stuff>
```

I'm expecting that the base class' `get` function while called will call the super class `get` function and check if the user already submitted the file.

I get:

```
TypeError at /estatisticas super() argument 1 must be type, not WSGIRequest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood how to use `super()`. You'd pass in the current class and an instance or class for the second argument, not the `request` object. The result of that call is a special object that knows how to find and bind attributes on the parent classes by disregarding the current class.

In a `staticmethod` context, you would have to pass in the current class as *both arguments*:

```
class Estatisticas(DatasetRequired):
    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        super(Estatisticas, Estatisticas).get(request)
        # <do various other stuff>
```

I'm really not sure why you are using a `staticmethod` here. When handling a request, a special instance is created for a view, so you normally use *normal instance methods*. At that point, in Python 3, you can use `super()` with no arguments:

```
class DatasetRequired(View):

    def get(self, request):
        # <redirects the user>

class Estatisticas(DatasetRequired):

    def get(self, request):
        super().get(request)
        # <do various other stuff>
```

Python has enough context to know that `super()` needs `Estatisticas` and `self` as arguments without you having to name those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very detailed. You're right, It's cleaner without @staticmethod. I though staticmethods are faster than normal ones. But it seems that I had no idea of what I'm using. The problem is that I get no error, but it seems that Django isn't redirecting also in the super class.

Comment: @testin3r: that'd be a separate problem, perhaps worthy of a new question, sorry.

Comment: No problem. It seems that this super class return just returns to the base class and not returns to the http reponse...

Comment: @testin3r: yes, it's *just a method call*. If you are returning a result from `get()` in the parent class and you don't want to ignore that result, then your new `.get()` method should use that result.